# Popup open triggered by DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, datatrigger

I am trying to open popup according to data change in my ViewModel:

Popup is defined as this:

```
 <Popup x:Name="popup"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Focusable="False"
IsHitTestVisible="False"
Placement="Bottom"
PopupAnimation="Slide"
StaysOpen="False">... </Popup>
```

And there I have user control

```
<UserControl>
 ...
<ControlTemplate>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PopupOpened}" Value="True">
         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
             <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPopup}"/>
         </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
     </DataTrigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

And my animation is defined as (in resources):

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="ShowPopup">
 <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="True" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
```

If I trigger this animation from EventTrigger on some control's triggers (button for example) it works correctly.

It doesn't work correctly inside DataTrigger.

EDIT:

I found an issue: 
If you are controlling Popup.IsOpen property with Animation + binding, Binding to that property will work only till you will use animation to change that property. After that Binding will not work anymore. Therefore you have to always change IsOpen property through Animation or Binding not mixing!

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your example which obscure the real issue.
Your `DataTrigger` element is not closed and 'StaticResources' should be `StaticResource`.

But ultimately, template for UserControl is not used right, you missed `UserControl.Template` setting. If we fix it, we'll see the exception:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PopupOpened}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPopup}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!-- Some content for template to have substance -->
            <TextBlock />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Here's the result:

> 'popup' name cannot be found in the name scope of
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.

The easiest way to actually do that, IMO, is a simple direct binding:

```
<Popup x:Name="popup"
       IsOpen="{Binding PopupOpened, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Or, if you really need the trigger, you can move it to Popup itself:

```
<Popup x:Name="popup">
    <Popup.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PopupOpened}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="True" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Popup.Style>

    <TextBlock />
</Popup>
```